# How to position a button in android XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hey I have the code bellow for my buttons in XML and I would like the Anthem Button to be moved to the left hand side near the bottom corner and I will add a stop button in the bottom right, Could anyone advise me on how to do this?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/country1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="45sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivFlag1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sflag" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bEdinburgh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ivFlag1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Edinburgh"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bGlasgow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bEdinburgh"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Glasgow"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAberdeen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bGlasgow"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Aberdeen"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAnthem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bAberdeen"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Anthem Button, set `android:layout_alignParentLeft` or `android:layout_alignParentRight` to `true` will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Set following attributes in the Anthem button

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and following to the Stop button

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```